# swift how to append UIColor in array

Tags: swift, uicolor

my code is:

```
public var color = [UIColor]()
color.append(String(UIColor(dragInViews[i]!.backgroundColor)))
```

this code has an error:
`Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads`.

I'm trying to resolve problem but I don't know. What is the problem
how to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `String()` part (nor the `UIColor()` initializer), it's already a `UIColor` and the array is defined as an array of `UIColor`, so just appending it is more than enough.

```
public var color = [UIColor]()
color.append(dragInViews[i]!.backgroundColor)
```

Note that the `backgroundColor` property of a `UIView` *is already a color*, so there's no point in instantiating it again.

That particular error you're seeing is because you were trying to instantiate a color with its initializer in this way `UIColor(something)`, but the initializer that exists is `UIColor(white:, alpha:)` between others. Check out the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new array of UIColor type and in which you need to append color value not string type directly color

```
var arrColor = [UIColor]()
arrColor.append(UIColor(dragInViews[i]?.backgroundColor ?? UIColor()))
```